# Controlar el registro de entrada y de salida SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla donde por medio de un aplicativo llegan unos registros el cual es entrada y salida de un empleado. todo funciona de manera correcta. esta construida en laravel con motor de bases de datos SQLSERVER

Por solicitud de cliente. me solicita que el empleado no puede marcar nuevamente el mismo día una vez haya finalizado su turno. tengo lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla de asistencia. cuando el empleado marca su registro de entrada en el campo **date_begin** se guarda correctamente. una vez el empleado sale. los campos **updated_at** y **date_end** automáticamente se insertan sus registros y finaliza la salida con el campo **closed** de tipo boleano.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer, es que si por alguna razón el empleado vuelve a marcar el mismo dia, el sistema no lo debe dejar porque ya el teóricamente cumplió su turno laboral. pero al día siguiente puede marcar sin problema.

Lo que he realizado por medio de un Trigger en la base de datos  que es el siguiente

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_validarMarcacion
ON assistance
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
DECLARE
@codentry varchar(50),
@fechain datetime, 
@fechaout datetime ,
@cerrado bit
SELECT @fechain = date_begin 
        From assistance 
        Where @fechain = date_begin and closed = @cerrado


IF @cerrado > 1
 
BEGIN
PRINT 'Lo siento, este registro ya cumplio su turno.'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Pero hasta el momento no lo he logrado. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en el cuadro rojo. el mismo **codentry "1351"** pudo ingresar dos veces en el mismo dia, cuando en realidad solo debe registrar solo un dia. lo que estoy intentando con el trigger es evitar ese segundo ingreso.

Comment: Tu duda no es clara ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: Claro, Mi duda es la siguiente. como puedo hacer yo que el usuario no pueda volver a ingresar al sistema en el mismo dia es decir. Un empleado marca su turno de entrada hoy a las 6:00 PM, y vuelve a registrar su salida a las 11:00 PM, pero si por alguna razon, el empleado vuelve a marcar. que no deje insertar su registro en la misma fecha o bien en el turno @BetaM

Comment: Eso queda claro, lo que no entiendo es donde esta el problema con el código que expones o donde tiene que ver Laravel aqui, debes ser un poco mas claro indicando que si ese trigger lo tienes entonces que fallo da

Comment: a ok, ya comprendo. bueno en realidad especifique que era laravel en caso de que alguien preguntara que framework era. todo funciona perfecto. lo que quiero hacer o bien intentarlo es con ese trigger evitar que esa insercion se haga, , voy a poner un ejemplo arriba @BetaM